# When is $S(m, k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(mn+k)}$ rational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> Let $k$ and $m$ be positive integers. Show that $$S(m, k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(mn+k)}$$ is rational if and only if $m$ divides $k$.

It is easy to see that when $m|k$ then the sum telescopes to a sum of finitely many rationals. But I am not able to prove the other way round. I tried integrals: $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^t}{1-x}dx$$ for rational $t$ however all attempts failed. I tried to use feynman trick as $$f(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}e^{\alpha (1-x)}\frac{1-x^t}{1-x}dx$$ however the expression for $f’$ is not manageable (if I want to integrate it again). I also thought of another way of doing the trick by using Ramanujan’s master theorem (as I was getting $x^{something}\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}$ but the integral was from 0 to 1).

Even if you tried to split the terms, convergence issues arise as $H_n$ diverges. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$S(m, k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(mn+k)}=\frac{1}{k}H_{\frac{k}{m}}$$ should be sufficient.

**Edit**

With regard to the integral approach

$$\int\frac{1-x^t}{1-x}dx=-\frac{x^{t+1} }{t+1}\, _2F_1(1,t+1;t+2;x)-\log (1-x)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function. Assuming $t >0$
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-x^t}{1-x}dx=\psi (t+1)+\gamma=H_t$$

Comment: I am unaware of $H_\frac{k}{m}$... Could you kindly elaborate? I think it is only defined for naturals not rationals...

Comment: @MATHSMOD. They are generalized harmonic numbers. They are only rational for integer values of the argument.

Comment: Ok but where can I find a detailed proof of that fact? Is there any good reference for this?

Comment: I am asking because I am not comfortable with digamma function etc.

Comment: @MATHSMOD. Have a look at my edit

Comment: Since the problem was here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146h150578p849561 I was looking for elementary solutions but it seems I will have to check when digamma function +$\gamma$ takes rational values...

Comment: @MATHSMOD $\psi (t+1)+\gamma=H_t$ is an identity

Comment: Ok I understand that much but how do you calculate when it is a rational number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118237/discussion-between-maths-mod-and-claude-leibovici).